# Does there exist a non-negative valued compactly supported function such that its Fourier transform only vanishes at a given point?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

My question is as follows: Given $t_0\in\mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a non-negative valued compactly supported function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ such that its Fourier transform, $\widehat f\left( t \right)$, only vanishes at $t_0$, $-t_0$?

Comment: Well, the Fourier transform of a real-valued function is hermitian, so I think you should at least have $\widehat f(-t_0)=0$ too

Comment: Yes. I completely agree with you.

Comment: So are you looking for a compact-supported, real-valued function such that $\widehat{f}$ vanishes only at $-t_0,0,t_0$ or what?

Comment: Yes. I wish to construct a function satisfying the given properties.

Comment: Is $\widehat{f}$ allowed to have complex zeroes other than $t_0,-t_0$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Why did you include $0$ in your list? If $f$ is **non-negative**, this implies $\widehat{f}(0) = \int f \, dx \geq 0$ with equality iff $f \equiv 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: No. $\hat f$ is not allowed to have complex zeroes. Note that $\hat f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f(x)$ is supported on $[-1,1]$ we have that $\widehat{f}(s)$ is an entire function of exponential type $1$ by [Paley-Wiener theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Wiener_theorem). If $\widehat{f}$ is not allowed to have any complex root out of $\pm t_0$, then
$$g(s)=\frac{\widehat{f}(s)}{s^2-t_0^2}$$
is an entire function of exponential type $1$ with no roots, hence $g(s)=\exp(as+b)$ by Hadamard's theorem. In this case, however, by considering the inverse Fourier transform we do not get a real valued function.

Comment: I'm wondering whether or not the inverse Fourier transform of $g$ has compactly supported.

Comment: @Cao: I bet not, since it is not square integrable over horizontal lines (second part of Paley-Wiener theorem).